# Text missing when attempting to read .txt file with scanner

Tags: java

I am using the following code in order to read a `.txt` file located in my root project directory, however, I am consistently met with output not containing the entirety of the file's body. My code is as follows:

```
public void readFile() throws IOException {
    int index = 0;
    int indexT = 1;
    File fileName = new File(file);
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fileName);
    while (inFile.hasNext()) {
        String line = inFile.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        if (indexT%3 == 0) {
            fileList[index] = inFile.nextLine();
        } else if (indexT == 1 || indexT == 4 || indexT == 7){
            playList[index] = inFile.nextLine();
        } else {
            break;
        }
        index++;
        indexT++;
    }
    inFile.close();
}
```

I have gone through similar questions and have been unable to determine the problem with my code. As far as I can see, it should be working perfectly. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a loop that is reading the lines one by one, but then you're breaking out of it on line 2. It's just not going to go any further than that.

```
while (inFile.hasNext()) {
    if (indexT%3 == 0) {
      //...
    } else if (indexT == 1 || indexT == 4 || indexT == 7){
      //...
    } else {
        break;
    }
    indexT++;
}
```

indexT starts on 1, which you have a case for, then it is incremented. This time, there's no special case, so it reaches "break". And breaks out of the loop. So.. no more lines are read.